# MySQL - Get most "liked" users in the past month

Tags: mysql, database, unix, social-media-like

I have a "like" system on a community forum. All internal likes are stored in a database called log_like.

```
CREATE TABLE `log_like` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_member` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `id_message` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_poster` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_member` (`id_member`),
  KEY `id_message` (`id_message`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I need to get the last month most liked member ID's (id_poster field in the DDL above). So I probably need to GROUP and COUNT how many times the same "id_poster" appears in records of the **past month**. I want to LIMIT it to the 10 most liked. The field "time" stores the unix time for reference.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT 
  id_poster, 
  COUNT(1) AS like_count
FROM 
  log_like
WHERE 
  time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-12-01')
GROUP BY 
  id_poster
ORDER BY 
  like_count 
DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This way I get the past month (November 2012) top result, instead of the past 30 days from now as suggested before. (Big thanks goes to Barmar for all the work)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id_poster, count(*) like_count
from log_like
where time > unix_timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 1 month))
group by id_poster
order by like_count desc
limit 10
```

It would be best if you had an index on `id_poster`.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I assume that date_sub() is based on MySQL date, and I have the time reference in Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch). Because of that, I get no results with your MySQL query.

Comment: I've added the `unix_timestamp()` function. You couldn't figure that out by yourself, either?

Comment: Yes, after my reply I have added UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), because I have the time field is in unix timestamp (seconds since epoch). However, I'm not getting the SUM of likes for each top member, instead I get integer "1" in the result set. I would like to SUM each member like, or, in other words, the number of times the top 10 id_poster is referenced in database (one row equals to one like).

Comment: That's what `count(*)` does, it counts the number of rows.

Comment: Just fixed it to add the missing `desc` in `order by`. It was showing the least liked instead of most liked. :)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this returns the top from the last 30 days from now. Do you know how can I get only the past month likes (November 2012) instead? Thank you.

Comment: Change the condition to: `where time between unix_timestamp('2012-11-01') and unix_timestamp('2012-12-01')`. This is all really basic stuff, you need to get out your SQL textbook or hire someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: That's it. Please notice that that was in fact part of the main question. Thank you again, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, count(*) as '#oflikes' from log_like
WHERE 
  time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-11-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-12-01')
LIMIT 10;
```